# 2D array replacing values according conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got a 10 x 10 array with the following values:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];
```

In this 2D array, I have to randomly choose six values of 0, either horizontally or vertically (also random) and replace them with the value 6.
I've done this with the following code:

```
function tekenGrootstSchip(bord) {
    rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    directie = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2));
    counter = 0;
    if (directie == 0) { 
    for(y = rand2; y < 10; y++) {
        if(counter < 6) {
            bord[rand][y] = 6;
            counter++;
    }
    }
    for(y = rand2; y > 0; y--) {
        if(counter < 6) {
            bord[rand][y] = 6;
            counter++;
    }
    }
    } else {
        for(x = rand; x < 10; x++) {
            if(counter < 6) {
                bord[x][rand2] = 6;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        for(x = rand; x > 0; x--) {
            if(counter < 6) {
                bord[x][rand2] = 6;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this for the value 6, I also have to do this for the value 4. The rules for value 4 are a bit different however. You can't place a 4 on a 6, neither can you place a 4 next to a 6. And the value 4 only takes four places (so 4x1, while a 6 is 6x1)

So if my randomly generated direction is horizontal, my bord[x-1][y], bord[x][y] and bord[x+1][y], with x and y initialized at the random value, with y going up to y+1, y+2, y+3, y+4 (4x1). All these values have to be checked against == 0, if true, replacing the zeroes with fours can be initialized otherwise not. If so, I have to generate a new [x][y] and check these conditions again until I can change four zeroes in my 2D array succesfully.

Although I have a general idea of implementing this, I would have a bug that, if for instance one null-value would be replaced with a four, but the one next to it can't be replaced since it's next to a != 0 value, I would be stuck with a "illegal" four.

If anyone could help me out in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Two general hints: 1) instead of generating random coordinates and checking them, enumerate all possible positions for a ship and choose randomly from that list. 2) once a ship is placed, mark neighbouring  cells with some non-zero value, so that you can only check for 0 in subsequent placements.

Comment: is 4 considered next to a 6 if it is in diagonal? (idem for a 6 in (x,y), is a 4 in (x+1,y+1) invalid?)

Comment: To enumerate the possible positions. You would firstly check the direction (horizontally/vertically) then return all the four consecutive zero-value coordinates, check these coordinates if their neighbours are non-zero value coordinates, and return all the ones without non-zero value neighbours, correct?

Comment: @user753642, I didn't include that in my original post, but that would also be illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### feasibility

We can (trivially) show that whatever the `6` configuration chosen, we can always put the `4`s.

Indeed, the maximal cover area of a 6 is 9 (a 3x3 square)

```
000
060
000
```

(we can't put a 4 in the border surrounding the 6).

So a bound for the maximal 6 configuration covered area is 6*9=54

```
000000xxxx
060060xxxx
000000xxxx
000000xxxx
060060xxxx
000000xxxx
000000xxxx
060060xxxx
000000xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

and we can put as many 4 in the squares containing `'x'` (which is way more than 4)

#### 6-generation

Let's assume the board is indiced as follow:

```
0   1  2  3 ...  9
10 11 12  ...   19 
...
90...           99
```

let x towards the bottom and y to the right

A square holding value `id` can be found at (x,y)=`((id - id%10)/10, id%10)` and reciprocally
`id:(x,y)->x*10+y`

So we will only consider numbers between 0 and 99 (since we can **find back** their associated position(x,y) in the grid)

I will use the copy-pasted below `getRandomInt` taken shamelessly from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

Finally we can draw between 0 and 99. If number already exists then discard it, otherwise take it

```
let indices = new Set
while(indices.size < 6){
    let idx = getRandomInt(0,99)
    if(!indices.has(idx)){
        indices.add(idx)
    }
}
return [...indices]
```

#### 4-generation

- We can apply the same stragy as before: draw a random number between 0 and 99 and discard it as long as it is not valid, until 4 valid positions are found

  1. build the invalid set due to the 6 positionned

```
    let invalids = new Set
    indices.forEach(idx=>{
        let [x,y] = [(idx - idx%10)/10, idx%10]
        //add the adjacent squares
        for(let i = -1; i<=1; ++i){
            for(let j = -1; j<= 1; ++j){
                if( 0<=x+i<10  && 0 <= y+j < 10){//if the cell in the board....
                    invalids.add( (x+i)*10 + y+j )
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

2. draw except from the invalid set

```
    let out = []
    while(out.length < 4){
        let idx = getRandomInt(0,99)
        if(!invalids.has(idx)){
            invalids.add(idx)
            out.push(idx)
        }
    }
    return out
```

That approach may be not that efficient in worst case: we would have about 54% probability of drawing an invalid number!

We can thus consider an array of only the valid numbers, and draw from it

```
let valids = Array(100).fill(0).reduce((oks, x,i)=>{
    if(invalids.has(i)) return oks
    return oks.push(i),oks
},[])

//take numbers from that array
let out = []
for(let i = 0; i<4; ++i){
    let idx = getRandomInt(0,valids.length)
    //notice that here we take the elem from valids
    //not just the idx from getRandomInt
    out.push(valids[idx])

    //and we takeout the element from valids
    valids.splice(idx, 1);
}
return out
```

Comment: About to go sleep, I'll read through everything when I wake up. Appreciate the help a lot!